# как нарисовать треугольник в python?

Tags: python, pygame

как нарисовать треугольник в python?

Answer (score 4):

Элементарно:

1. Выучить Python
2. Освоить Matplotlib.
3. После этого рисуем хоть треугольник хоть ромбоикосидодекаэдр.

А вообще-то Python - это что-бы программировать, а рисовать - это Photoshop или Paint.